# MySql filter query

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

I'm trying to create a product filters feature and I'm having trouble trying to get the right query together based on what a user has selected. lets say the tables are:

```
product_tb
+-----------+
|product_sku|
+-----------+
|ABC        |
|XYZ        |
|-----------|

product_attribute_tb

+-----------+--------------+---------------+
|product_sku|attribute_name|attribute_value|
+-----------+--------------+---------------|
|ABC        |colour        |red            |
|ABC        |size          |M              |
|XYZ        |colour        |red            |
|XYZ        |size          |L              |
|-----------|--------------|---------------|
```

What I'm looking for is that a product is only returned if all attributes exist, so if a user selects 'red' and 'M', it would return ABC only.

The reason why I haven't put these attributes on the product table is because its a SaaS application and the filters will differ for different applications.

I can't do multiple joins with hardcoded names and also there could be 40 potential filters against products do I'm looking for this to be flexible based on the name and content values of the product_attribute_tb as these can change.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious but if anyone could help it would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Martin.

Comment: please, reformat your tables, it is not clear what you are asking

Comment: I guess a question is, how do I get all products have have a colour of red and a size of L? Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
pat.product_sku
FROM
product_attribute_tb pat
INNER JOIN product_tb pt ON pat.product_sku = pt.product_sku
GROUP BY pat.product_sku
HAVING SUM((attribute_name = 'colour' AND attribute_value = 'red') OR (attribute_name = 'size' AND attribute_value = 'L')) >= 2;
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/599543/2/0)

Each boolean expression like `(attribute_name = 'colour' AND attribute_value = 'red')` and `(attribute_name = 'size' AND attribute_value = 'L')` returns true or false, 1 or 0. Then we sum those for each row and check if the `true` values are more than 2. Feel free to join to your `product_tb` table.

Comment: Nothing easier than this. Added it to my answer.

Comment: looks good. Seems a little slow but I can work on this as the query is quite complex already.

Really appreciate the help.
Thanks,
Martin

Comment: If this is slow for you, you might have to work on your indexing of the table.

Comment: yeah, just indexed it and the charset was different on the product and product_attribute product_sku column, updated those and all good now.

Once again. Thanks!!